# rake assets:precompile cannot load such file -- uglifier error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I want to run my application in production mode, when I pre-compile my assets using following command

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I am getting following error:

```
MYPCC:/media/New Volume/Rails$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
    rake aborted!
    cannot load such file -- uglifier
      (in /media/New Volume/Rails/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/bootstrap.rb:45:in `expand_js_compressor'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/bootstrap.rb:18:in `block in run'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:14:in `call'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:14:in `compressor'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:18:in `compress'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.0.4/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265:in `block in js_compressor='
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.0.4/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.0.4/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
    /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sprockets-2.0.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:175:in `block in evaluate'
```

My Gemfile contains:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

Run

```
bundle install
```

Please suggest..

Comment: Please run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: Getting same error as above, I think I have to use require directive in application.js file..not sure

Comment: Can you please post your application.js

Comment: its blank now..nothing is there in that file currently.

Comment: Nothing is there? Really? Whats your Rails version btw. Did you delete everything in your application.js?

Comment: Yes just to check why assets are not compiling..I moved my custom function in another file..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37934/discussion-between-ashwini-and-stevanity)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set RAILS_GROUPS=assets. So run it like this:

```
RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Think this doesn't makes sense.. rails is already adding it as it's visible on the second line of the post: /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby [..] RAILS_GROUPS=assets